# How Do I Scroll to Specific Text(Horizontally) in a TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview

Hey Guys I want the Vertical as well as Horizontal Scroll View to Scroll and take us to the Position of Text that has been given by the user.

```
  <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout">


        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/scrollviewbackground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_activity_third_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Loading.." />

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </ScrollView>
```

I Got the **Y Coordinate** But was not able to Find The **X Coordinate**.

```
  int y = textview.getLayout().getLineTop(LineNumberHere);
```

I Already Know Which Line the Text Is in But Not Able To Find the X Coordinate so that I can Scroll the Horizontal Scroll View to the Position of the Text.

I do set the Text In TextView Using JAVA Code.

Thanks In Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text position given by user is `inputPosition`, try the following:

```
int x = textview.getLayout().getOffsetForHorizontal(LineNumberHere, inputPosition);
```